# EventHandler with programmatically added control in separate class

Tags: asp.net, event-handling

Okay, so  I have two classes. One is a page with a Panel. The other is a class which I am using to generate a set of controls. For example, I use an instance of the "AddNote" class to call a method which programmatically generates a TextBox, some Labels, a Button, etc. which AddNote returns and I add to the set of controls in my Panel.

One of my controls is a DropDownList. I want the change in selection to trigger a method in my AddNote class:

```
public Control[] GetNoteControls()
{

...

accountDropDownList.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.accountDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged);
accountDropDownList.AutoPostBack = true;
...
return controls;
}
```

And also in my AddNote class:

```
public void accountDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
//Do some stuff
}
```

In my page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
...
Control[] controls = AddNote.GetNoteControls();
foreach(Control c in controls){
    PanelControls.Controls.Add(c);
}
...
}
```

The controls are added and everything goes well. But accountDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged is never fired. How can I use this method?

Comment: How do you know that the event is never fired? Also - what is the relation between `AddNote.GetControls` and `AddNote.GetNoteControls` methods?

Comment: I mean the method is never fired. Because I stepped through it. And sorry, that other bit is a typo, they are supposed to be the same thing

Comment: Do you assign control ID to `accountDropDownList`?

Comment: Show complete code that creates and fills `accountDropDownList`.

Comment: I found the problem. It was an embarrassing, silly thing -- another control was doing a postback and messing up the controls on the page. I should have stepped through it better =[

Comment: The above code works fine, for anyone interested.